# How to loop in a simple Python Game?

Tags: python, loops

I'm very new to Python but have written a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

It's code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

name = raw_input("Hi, I'm PyVa.  What is your name: ")
print('Hi',name, end='.')
yesorno = raw_input('  Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?: ')
yesorno = str(yesorno)



if yesorno == str('Yes'):
    choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
    print('Ok')
    your_choice = raw_input('Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: ')
    print('My turn...')

    my_choice = random.choice(choices)
    print('I choose,', my_choice)
    if your_choice == my_choice:
        print('We both choose the same, it is a draw.')
    elif your_choice == 'Rock' and my_choice == 'Paper':
        print('I win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Scissors' and my_choice == 'Paper':
        print('You win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Paper' and my_choice == 'Rock':
        print('You win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Paper' and my_choice == 'Scissors':
        print('I win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Rock' and my_choice == 'Scissors':
        print('You win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Scissors' and my_choice == 'Rock':
        print('I win!')

    again = raw_input('Would you like to play again?:')

    #this is where I would like to loop to the start depending on input.



else:
    print('Ok, maybe we can play later, bye.')
```

Now I can imagine this isn't even remotely elegant code and that there must be more precise ways to write what I am trying to do. (Please give any pointers you have time to).

My main concern is how to correctly insert a loop for after each game ends to either return to the second block ie. the start or the game, or to simply end, based on the raw_input from the user.

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You don't need `str('Yes')`. `'Yes'` is already a string. The same applies to the return value of `raw_input`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, my rep doesn't allow me to upvote or I would have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't have time to clean it up, but here's a way you can fix your specific issue. You wrap the game within a while loop that is always true, and exit when desired.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

name = raw_input("Hi, I'm PyVa.  What is your name: ")
print('Hi',name, end='.')

yesorno = raw_input('  Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?: ')

while(1):

    yesorno = str(yesorno)

    if yesorno == str('Yes'):
        choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
        print('Ok')
        your_choice = raw_input('Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: ')
        print('My turn...')

        my_choice = random.choice(choices)
        print('I choose,', my_choice)
        if your_choice == my_choice:
            print('We both choose the same, it is a draw.')
        elif your_choice == 'Rock' and my_choice == 'Paper':
            print('I win!')
        elif your_choice == 'Scissors' and my_choice == 'Paper':
            print('You win!')
        elif your_choice == 'Paper' and my_choice == 'Rock':
            print('You win!')
        elif your_choice == 'Paper' and my_choice == 'Scissors':
            print('I win!')
        elif your_choice == 'Rock' and my_choice == 'Scissors':
            print('You win!')
        elif your_choice == 'Scissors' and my_choice == 'Rock':
            print('I win!')

        again = raw_input('Would you like to play again? [y/n]:')

        if again is "y":
            next
        else:
            print('Thanks for playing!\n')
            exit()

    else:
        print('Ok, maybe we can play later, bye.')
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your solution.  It made the most sense to me.

Comment: I had to play around with the loop a bit and the indentations. In the end I simply changed yerorno variable to one I could use uniformally in the code and added an else statement in case of n.

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

name = raw_input("Hi, I'm PyVa.  What is your name: ")
print('Hi',name, end='.')
n = 0
while True:
    if 'y' in raw_input('Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?: ').lower() or n > 0:
        my_choice = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
        print('Ok')
        your_choice = raw_input('Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: ').lower()
        print('My turn...')
        print('I choose,', my_choice)
        if your_choice == my_choice:
            print('We both choose the same, it is a draw.')
        elif your_choice in ['rock', 'scissors'] and my_choice == 'paper':
            print('I win!')
        elif your_choice == 'paper' and my_choice in ['rock', 'scissors']:
            print('You win!')
        elif your_choice == 'rock' and my_choice == 'scissors':
            print('You win!')
        elif your_choice == 'scissors' and my_choice == 'rock':
            print('I win!')
        n += 1
        if not 'y' in raw_input('Would you like to play again?:').lower():
            break

    #this is where I would like to loop to the start depending on input.
```

It's also case insensitive now, kind of annoying when the game exits or you lose because you accidentally forgot to write your answer starting with a capital letter. I also simplified it a little bit using 'in'

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide working code for me. Based on my limited beginner knowledge I added a while loop based on another answer, and used else to check for a no, looping back on a yes. I'm going to study your changes so that I understand them and can incorporate the theory in any future instances where required.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any questions do not hesitate to contact me. I'm sure you'll write very nice code in no time!

Answer (score 0):

I would insert the loop there:

```
# ...

yesorno = raw_input('  Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?: ')

while yesorno == 'Yes':
    choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']

    # ...

    yesorno = raw_input('  Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?: ')

print('Ok, maybe we can play later, bye.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:

    <your code>

    if not 'y' in raw_input('Would you like to play again?: ').lower():
        break;
```

Comment: While this answer is correct and uses the same logic as my answer, I strongly recomend taking a look at my answer if you want to avoid having the initial question asked multiple times. The short is also shorter among some other things.

Comment: I assume he will add the initial print outside the fragment, not mentioned, but seems quite trivial to me.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is to remove the unnecessary variables and instead put the actual game in a function. This allows you to call it once WITHOUT asking if the player wants to replay, and then make a while loop where the user can decide if he wants to play on. I hope this helps. I couldn't test this myself as I use Python 2.7, but aside from some potential syntax differences the code should work.
I suggest something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

name = raw_input("Hi, I'm PyVa.  What is your name: ")
print('Hi',name, end='.')
yesorno = raw_input('  Would you like to play Rock, Paper, Scissors?: ')
if yesorno == 'y':
    play()
def play():
        choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
        print('Ok')
        your_choice = raw_input('Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors: ')
        print('My turn...')

    my_choice = random.choice(choices)
    print('I choose,', my_choice)
    if your_choice == my_choice:
        print('We both choose the same, it is a draw.')
    elif your_choice == 'Rock' and my_choice == 'Paper':
        print('I win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Scissors' and my_choice == 'Paper':
        print('You win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Paper' and my_choice == 'Rock':
        print('You win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Paper' and my_choice == 'Scissors':
        print('I win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Rock' and my_choice == 'Scissors':
        print('You win!')
    elif your_choice == 'Scissors' and my_choice == 'Rock':
        print('I win!')
while True:
    play_again = raw_input('Play Again?(Y/N)')
    if play_again.lower() == 'y':
        play()
    elif play_again.lower() == 'n':
        print('Ok, maybe we can play later, bye.')
        break
    else:
        print('That isn\'t a valid option...')
```